# Quartz.NET JobListener for failed jobs

Tags: c#, quartz.net

In my Quartz.NET based application, I have a JobListener that audits all jobs executed to an audit table. However, I also want a listener to detect whenever any sort of error occurs, so I can catch this and email an email address that there is an error, and maybe find the specific error (i.e. my program moves files around, so an error could be a path doesn't exist).

How do I listen for failed jobs, and also is it possible to detect whether there is a huge number of errors, and in that case only send a few emails rather than an email for every single error?

Comment: If you are satisfied with an answer accept that answer by clicking on the tick mark icon to the left of the answer. This will help others who are looking for the same kind of question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To detect whenever any sort of error occurs you will want to implement a listener, either a Job listener or a Trigger listener, or probably you'll want both: http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/lesson_7.html

You can attach the listeners by calling methods on the IScheduler object you create.

What we do to roll-up multiple emails is use a logging system, specifically [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/).  We use a [BufferingWrapper](http://nlog-project.org/wiki/BufferingWrapper_target) around a [Mail target](http://nlog-project.org/wiki/Mail_target) so that the error log is sent after some specified number of events has been logged (e.g., 200) or after a specified timeout period has elapsed after the last logged error (e.g., 2 minutes).